# pthread_cancel with two running processes

Tags: c, multithreading

I want to use pthread_cancel to cancel my "timer" thread when my process is done executing. Basically we are making a modified terminal as a project. When I call sleep 300 in one terminal, I want to be able to open another terminal, run the same program, but call "pkill -HUP sleep" and cancel the sleep call AND the timer. However, the timer keeps running with my current solution.

```
  else if (pid > 0){
    pthread_t thread;
    int threadError = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, timer, NULL);
    if (threadError != 0){
      exit(1);
    }
    int status = 0;
    wait(&status);
    if (WIFEXITED(status)){
    // how do I change this to kill the other thread?
      threadError = pthread_cancel(thread);
      if (threadError != 0)
        exit(1);
      printf("Child exited with code %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
  else{ // child
    // run command and capture error with errorNumber
    int errorNumber = execvp(argv[0], argv);
    if (errorNumber == -1){
      logerror(5, "execvp", "Error running command.");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
```

I'll include my timer function as well.

```
void * timer(void * nothing){
  //tracks seconds of execution
  time_t start = time(NULL);
  for(;;){
    sleep(UPDATETIME); //constant set to 1
    printf("Elapsed time: %ld seconds\n", time(NULL) - start);
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

I've been pouring over the man page for pthread_cancel and I can't seem to find a way to cancel this thread when a new instance of this program is being run.

Edit: I assume my problem is actually that this pkill command isn't terminating my child process properly instead of there being a problem with pthread_cancel. I'll edit the above to include my child process.

Answer (score 0):

pthread_join(); is a better than pthread_cancel(); Please check the documentation and examples...